# Register and calling IHealthCheckPublisher on internal IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

If I have an internal IServiceCollection, on which I've registered healtcheck services and options

```
        services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(extensions.ConfigurationCore.HealthCheckOptionsSetup);

        services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, ConnectionHealthCheck>()
            .AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<ConnectionHealthCheck>("[].[HealthCheck]");
```

How can I set my internal library to trigger this as it was registered on the Application IServiceCollection ? I guess in asp.net core when the WebApplication is Build and Run some services take care of some scheduler, but since I do not build a WebApplication or Application or anyhing like this in my library , how can I achieve same behaviour as if I were to register the services directly on the the WebApplication itself

```
        services.TryAddSingleton<IInternalInfrastructure>(
            serviceProvider =>
            {
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

                IInternalConfigurationDefinitionBuilder definitionBuilder = new ConfigurationDefinitionBuilder(new ConfigurationDefinition());

                /// <summary>
                ///     Defaults
                /// </summary>
                definitionBuilder.UseReconnectRetryPolicy<ExponentialRetry>()
                    .UseRateLimitPolicy<NoRateLimit>()
                    .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                    .LogTo(Console.Out)
                    .UseConnectionHealthChecks(
                        options =>
                        {
                            options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30_000);
                            options.Period = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60_000);
                        });

                definitionBuilderAction.Invoke(serviceProvider, definitionBuilder);

                return new InternalInfrastructure(
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(),
                    definitionBuilder.Definition);
            });
        services.TryAddSingleton<IInternalServiceProvider>(
            serviceProvider =>
            {
                IServiceCollection internalServices = new ServiceCollection();

                services.Where(service => service.ServiceType.AssemblyQualifiedName!.StartsWith("Microsoft.")).ForEach(serviceDescriptor => internalServices.Add(serviceDescriptor));

                return new InternalServiceProvider(
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInternalInfrastructure>()
                        .ConfigureServices(internalServices));
            });
```

Here 'service' is the Application level IServiceCollection.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call .AddHealthChecks()           .AddCheck<ConnectionHealthCheck>("[].[HealthCheck]");  in your extension method?

Comment: No, I mean I am creating an managing an internel serviceProvider inside this library and would like to know how to trigger the healthchecks. So they are registered on an internal service collection, I then build this internal service collection and I get an intenral service provider